# How does Dirac form this conjugate imaginary equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, terminology, hilbert-space

On page 30 of Dirac's book

$$\xi|P\rangle = a|P\rangle\tag{12}$$

He then says

> Suppose we have a solution of (12) and we form the conjugate imaginary equation, which will read
>
> $$\langle P|\xi = a\langle P|$$
>
> in view of the reality of $\xi$ and $a$

To show this, I tried from (12)

$$\langle P|\xi|P\rangle = \langle P|a|P\rangle$$
$$\langle P|\overline\xi|P\rangle = \langle P|\overline a|P\rangle$$

And since $a$ and $\xi$ are both real

$$\langle P|\xi|P\rangle = \langle P|a|P\rangle$$

But I don't see how I can now remove the $|P\rangle$ on both sides to get the conjugate imaginary equation.

Comment: WATCH OUT: a *real* operator in Dirac's terminology is a Hermitian one

Comment: Why don't you just apply the $\phantom{A}^\dagger$ to $(12)$ and be done with it?

Comment: See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101437/

Comment: @ACuriousMind when in doubt, *give 'em the ol' dagger*

Comment: @ACuriousMind This is page 30 of his book where the basic mathematical framework is based around there being a function of a ket, amongst other things. You really need to have a look at the book to see what I mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sort of trick involved in

> removing the $|P\rangle$ on both sides to get the conjugate imaginary equation
>
> $$\langle P|\xi|P\rangle = \langle P|a|P\rangle \tag1 $$

is quite common but it is indeed nontrivial to grasp the first time. In essence, you leverage the fact that in an equation of the form 
$$
⟨\psi|\hat A|\phi⟩=⟨\psi|\hat B|\phi⟩\tag2
$$
you have two linear functionals $⟨\psi|\hat A$ and $⟨\psi|\hat B$ which give the same result for all states $|\phi⟩\in\mathcal H$. This is exactly the criterion for equality of functions:

> $f=g$ if and only if $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ (modulo domain considerations).

Therefore, you can conclude from (2) that $⟨\psi|\hat A=⟨\psi|\hat B$, which effectively means that you can "cancel out" the $|\phi⟩$ as long as the equality is valid for all such states.

That said, you've gotten yourself in some trouble in (1), because $P$ appears on both sides. This can maybe be fixed from there, but your best bet is to take a few steps back. Instead of multiplying your original equation
$$
\xi|P⟩=a|P⟩ \tag {Dirac's (12)}
$$
on the left by $⟨P|$, take its inner product with an arbitrary state $|\phi⟩$:
$$
⟨\phi|\xi|P⟩=⟨\phi|a|P⟩
$$
and then take the conjugate to conclude, via hermicity of $\xi$ and reality of $a$, that 
$$⟨P|\xi|\phi⟩=⟨P|a|\phi⟩$$
for arbitrary $|\phi⟩$. From this, then you can conclude that 
$$⟨P|\xi=⟨P|a.$$

Comment: Right... but @ACuriousMind's suggestion of just daggering the equation is simpler and more to the point (IMO)

Comment: Yes. But that requires a solid knowledge that $(\xi |P⟩)^\dagger=⟨P|\xi$; you can treat this answer as a working proof of that fact.