# On linear operators and their complex qualities

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

In the Principles of Quantum Mechanics, Dirac states that all linear operators $\alpha$ over our vector field (over the complex numbers) can be expressed as the sum of a real and an imaginary part $\alpha=\beta + i\gamma$ where $\beta$ is real (that is $\beta=\bar{\beta}$ (where $\bar{\alpha}$ is defined s.t. if $|A\rangle=\alpha|B\rangle$, $\langle A|=\langle B|\bar{\alpha}$)) and $\gamma$ is imaginary ($\gamma=-\bar{\gamma}$). Can somebody help me prove this?

Comment: More on Dirac's book on QM: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101437/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that
$$ A = \frac{1}{2}(A + A^\dagger) + \frac{1}{2}(A - A^\dagger) $$
where the summands are Hermitian and anti-Hermitian as desired.

Comment: I am sorry, what is $A^{\dagger}$ and hermitian and anti-hermitian?

Comment: @Ivan: Oh, in your notation, $A^\dagger = \bar A$ and Hermitian/anti-Hermitian are the properties $A^\dagger = A$ and $A^\dagger = -A$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition $$\alpha^*=\bar{\alpha}$$ and is called a complex conjugate so for the real part, the complex conjugate is itself while the imaginary part takes on the opposite sign.

To prove that 
$$\langle A|=\langle B|\bar{\alpha}$$ first define this equation to be the complex transpose of
 $$|A\rangle=\alpha|B\rangle$$

For the complex number alpha, the complex transpose is simply the complex conjugate. The complex transpose is just the complex conjugate of the individual components of **A** and **B** as well as turning the row vectors to column vectors or the column vectors to row vectors, also called the transpose of the vectors. Hence the name ***complex transpose*** (Refer to wikipedia complex transpose).
  If we denote a complex transpose as * because I don't know how to make that t cross sign thing, then

$$\langle A|=|A\rangle^*=(\alpha|B\rangle)^*=\langle B|\bar{\alpha}$$ 
$$_{Q.E.D}$$
P.S

I don't know if this violates the rule on giving near complete or complete answers so if it does please tell me and I will either delete or edit this post.

Comment: The question is why all linear operators can be expressed as the sum of a real and an imaginary part, not what you are doing here.

Comment: Well then it is similar to how complex numbers can be expressed as a sum of real and imaginary parts. The operators can also be split into real and complex parts. Sorry I thought he meant to help prove whatever I wrote up there.